# Dart Analysis server terminated and lost connection to the device

Tags: flutter, dart

i face two problem:

> Dart Analyzer server has terminated
>
> lost connection to the device

i also raised the issue on flutter, dart repo but don't get any response, i am not able to work on any project. i also did  clean windows installation two time but still the same problem, i check all the available solution here on stackoverflow also all the issue on flutter and dart github repo, please someone help me to solve this problem.

flutter doctor -v result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.418], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (11 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
exit code 0
```

Log files:

```
Dart Code extension: 3.7.1
Flutter extension: 3.7.1 (not activated)
VS Code: 1.41.1
Platform: win
HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined

Sun Dec 22 2019 [14:21:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Log file started
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world:
            Mobile? true
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? false
            Flutter Repo? false
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\.flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\.flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\vendor\flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\vendor\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\src\flutter
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\src\flutter for flutter.bat
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk for dart.exe
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[2:21:51 PM] [General] [Info] Extension:Startup timing: 77ms
[2:21:52 PM] [General] [Info] Analyzer:Startup timing: 433ms
[2:21:55 PM] [General] [Info] Analyzer:FirstAnalysis timing: 2240ms
[2:21:57 PM] [General] [Info] Checking 1 projects for supported platforms
[2:21:57 PM] [General] [Info] Supported platforms for the workspace are ios, android
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Starting debug session...
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info]     workspace: C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Using found common entry point: C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world\lib\main.dart
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Using workspace as cwd: C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\hwvs\hello_world
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Detected launch project as Flutter
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Using Flutter debug adapter for this session
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Checking for errors before launching
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Spawning a new flutter debugger
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Debug session starting...
    {
        "noDebug": true,
        "program": "C:\\Users\\Akash\\Desktop\\hwvs\\hello_world\\lib\\main.dart",
        "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Akash\\Desktop\\hwvs\\hello_world",
        "name": "Dart & Flutter",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [],
        "vmAdditionalArgs": [],
        "vmServicePort": 0,
        "dartPath": "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\dart.exe",
        "maxLogLineLength": 2000,
        "pubPath": "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\pub.bat",
        "pubSnapshotPath": "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\snapshots\\pub.dart.snapshot",
        "debugSdkLibraries": false,
        "debugExternalLibraries": false,
        "showDartDeveloperLogs": true,
        "useFlutterStructuredErrors": true,
        "debuggerHandlesPathsEverywhereForBreakpoints": true,
        "evaluateGettersInDebugViews": true,
        "previewDebuggerStepBack": false,
        "forceFlutterVerboseMode": false,
        "flutterTrackWidgetCreation": true,
        "flutterMode": "debug",
        "flutterPlatform": "default",
        "flutterPath": "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat",
        "deviceId": "emulator-5554",
        "deviceName": "Pixel 3a API 29 (android-x86)",
        "showMemoryUsage": false,
        "debugServer": 55153,
        "debuggerType": 2
    }
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Warn] Did not find session c1e7e06d-fbe6-48be-9a1c-b461e7b8c7e6 to handle dart.launching. There were 0 sessions:
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Warn] Event will be queued and processed when the session start event fires
[2:24:39 PM] [General] [Info] Processing delayed event dart.launching for session c1e7e06d-fbe6-48be-9a1c-b461e7b8c7e6
[2:25:27 PM] [General] [Info] Debugger:SessionDuration timing: 47627ms (Flutter)
[2:25:40 PM] [General] [Error] Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:413:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:401:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:301:11)
    at m.sendMessage (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45556)
    at m.sendMessage (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:39197)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at m.sendRequest (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45176)
    at m.editGetFixes (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:290549)
    at t.FixCodeActionProvider.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:436166)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:435700
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:435445)
    at t.FixCodeActionProvider.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:436006)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:441239
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at t.RankingCodeActionProvider.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:441230)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:440679
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:440424)
    at t.RankingCodeActionProvider.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\…
[2:25:40 PM] [General] [Error] Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:413:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:401:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:301:11)
    at m.sendMessage (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45556)
    at m.sendMessage (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:39197)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at m.sendRequest (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:45176)
    at m.editGetAssists (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:290272)
    at t.AssistCodeActionProvider.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:397337)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:396876
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:396621)
    at t.AssistCodeActionProvider.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:397178)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:441239
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at t.RankingCodeActionProvider.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:441230)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:440679
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\out\dist\extension.js:1:440424)
    at t.RankingCodeActionProvider.provideCodeActions (c:\Users\Akash\.vscode\extensions\dart-code.dart-code-3.7.1\o…
```

Comment: try to reinstall dart plugin in VScode.

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat i did but nothing has solved, same problem

Comment: It's certainly a bug with the latest version, I have the same problem since I updated my plugin version

Comment: so how do you solved this issue @SteveNosse

Comment: I didn't.. I'm waiting for a solution

Comment: ok, how much time have they take to resolve a issue, @SteveNosse

Comment: Can't tell you that

Comment: Sorry it's taken a few days for you to get a response on the issue tracker - it's been the weekend since you raised it. I've pinged a few people that might know more, but it's hard to track down without being able to reproduce it. Anything you can do to help (such as providing detailed instructions to repro starting from a `flutter create` project) would help things along. FWIW I don't believe this is a VS Code extension bug and suspect it was triggered by a Flutter upgrade.

Comment: Hello @DannyTuppeny its all started a week ago, when i was tested a demo app(mobile) for image classification but it failed in both VS code and android studio, since then neither my new project nor my old project run properly i got the same error that i mention in the issue. After i got these error i think it might be my system fault so that i did clean installation of window os two times, but still nothing has improved i got the same error, whether i run my old project or create a new project in both VS code and android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these are bugs from the previous releases:

[The Dart Analyzer has terminated.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43620) this should be fix by the current release of Flutter as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43620#issuecomment-727147375):

> this is fixed in Dart 2.10.4, which is included in 1.22.4 on the
> stable channel.

[Lost connection to device.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54970) could also be fixed by upgrading the [latest Flutter version](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54970#issuecomment-620420557).